# Will jquery empty() method clear the event listeners created through non jquery means

Tags: jquery, memory-leaks

I have an element with a lot of child elements. I want to clear the content of this element and replace it with new structure.

The child elements are assigned with various event listeners and not all of those listeners are created through jquery bind method.

If I use jquery's empty method to clear the element will it remove all the event listeners or will it clear only the listeners created through jquery bind method?

Answer (score 17):

As several commenters have mentioned, the jQuery docs say that empty() does indeed remove event handlers: http://api.jquery.com/empty/

Perhaps that wasn't the case when this question was posted, but this page is the first hit on Google.

Comment: Just experienced this, jQuery 1.12 `empty()` does indeed remove the listeners.

Comment: What are other alternatives for the `empty()` method? Just so to prevent event handlers to detach?

Answer (score 3):

You can unbind all listeners of a object with the **.unbind()** and leave the params empty

If you want to remove all the children of an element. just user **$("#parent").children().remove();**

With the **live()** and **die()** methods you can add eventhandlers to elements which do not yet exists yet. with **$(".element").live("click", function(){})** adds a function to all .element objects that are currently in your HTML or those who are added in the future.

Comment: Jquery's empty() documentation states this. "To avoid memory leaks, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from the child elements before removing the elements themselves." Shouldn't invoking empty() method is sufficient then? Why do I have to invoke unbind ?

Comment: Yes indeed, .empty() will do all above by itselve, to each child. If you are using .empty() you do not need to call .ubind() yourself. It will unbind events and clear all data saved within the nodes.

Answer (score -1):

it will not clear the event listeners. But you should use this event listeners as `live()` event, because, you are changing `DOM` elements dynamically.

for e.g:

```
$('a').live('click', function(){
   // your stuff
});
```

// jQuery 1.7 required for following code snippet

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(){
   // your stuff
});
```

Comment: This answer contradicts the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/empty/ "To avoid memory leaks, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from the child elements before removing the elements themselves.

If you want to remove elements without destroying their data or event handlers (so they can be re-added later), use .detach() instead."